# Multithreaded JavaFX UI

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I have two multithreading issues that are interwoven.

I have a SplitPane in a JavaFX desktop application using spring boot. On the left is a TreeView, on the right a TabPane. In the beginning the SplitPane devider is at the right edge hiding the TabPane. When the user selects an item in the tree two things shall happen in parallel:

First, depending on the selection ~10 tabs are created. The tabs differ depending on the selected object. Each tab shows detail data related to the selected object. Most tabs contain charts but also text.

Second, since the setup of the tabs takes a few seconds - data needs to be fetched from the DB - the idea was to "roll" the TabPane devider slowly to the left side, hiding the tree. This gives the user the impression that the application is still running and makes the transition softer. I don't like waiting, waiting,.. bang!

One trouble is, the Timeline (see below) I am using is stuttering and I can't make it work seamless in parallel to setup the tabs.

The creation of the tabs runs in a dedicated Task and each tab creator uses `Platform.runLater()`. Second trouble is, I am not sure whether this is the best way to code this. I mean, almost all tabs are hidden by the top one but all tabs are created one after the other in the application thread.

In other words, the pseudo code would look something like this:

```
KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(splitPane.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty(), 0.1);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), keyValue));
timeline.play();

Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
       Platform.runLater(()-> {
           createTabA();
       }

       ..

       Platform.runLater(()-> {
           createTabZ();
       }

       return null;
    }
};
Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

I also changed the order, having the Timeline after starting the Thread. It looks different but still not as expected.

How can I improve my multi-threading logic and get rid of the bucking?

BTW: In the real code I am already changing the cursor when this process runs, to make it more digestible for the user.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: TL;DR; [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Please add [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runnable`s passed to `Platform.runLater` run on the JavaFX application thread and using multiple calls of `Platform.runLater` from a background thread in rapid succession has the only benefit that JavaFX *could* decide to do layout between the `Tab` creations. The tab creations don't get and faster.

`Runnable`s passed to `Platform.runLater` shouldn't contain any long-running operations.

Instead create the tabs on the background thread ***but don't attach them to the scene from this thread.*** (Creating (parts of) a scene on a background thread is not an issue as long as you don't modify something that is attached to a `Scene`.)

If it's ok for you to add all the tabs at once at the end of the task, consider using a `Task<List<Tab>>` and returning the tabs.

```
Task<List<Tab>> task = new Task<List<Tab>>() {
    @Override public List<Tab> call() {
       List<Tab> result = new ArrayList<>(1 + 'Z' - 'A');

       for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
           result.add(createTab(c));
       }

       return result;
    }
};
task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> tabPane.getTabs().addAll(task.getValue()));
...
```

Otherwise create the `Tab`s on the background thread, but add them to the `TabPane` on the application thread:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
       for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
           final Tab tab = createTab(c);
           Platform.runLater(() -> tabPane.getTabs().add(tab));
       }

       return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The TabPane with all its tabs is already pre-definedand loaded as fxml. I only fetch the data and then "fill" the TextFields, Charts and so on. So the tabs are already attached to the scene graph. Can I kind of switch on/off elements while they are part of the scene graph? Would using setVisible() be sufficient? Thank you in advance!